# Email notification for low disk space in RabbitMQ hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, virtual-machine

Question:

Is there a way to set up email notifications in Azure Metrics when RabbitMQ hits the low disk space threshold? I'd also be happy if there was a way to set up a notification in RabbitMQ Management.

Problem:

When my disk space fills up it's generally due to the logging I have set up on the VM. I scheduled a cron job to remove old logs after x amount of time but for some unknown reason the cron job disappeared from the vm this last time and Rabbitmq started [blocking messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html).

I cleared up the disk space already so it's no longer red but below is where I'm notified the disk is full:

[image: Disk Space]

As I've mentioned, I'd like to be notified when my disk space is causing issue with RMQ. It's currently hosted in Azure and I thought there would be a metric for disk space but I've tried everything that sounds like it could potentially be the answer.

[image: Metrics]

The article above for the blocked messages talks about setting up alarms but it doesn't handle the problem in the way I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using disk metrics, you should take a look at performance counters. For Virtual Machines, there is `Logical Disk(_Total)\%Free Space` performance counter that you can capture and send to Azure Monitor. You should be able to create alerts based on the available free space.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-platform-metrics#view-multi-dimensional-performance-counter-metrics-in-metrics-explorer.